# How to get column records into row in my case using SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, stored-procedures

I have a table called `RelationData` which has 4 columns:

**RelationData**

```
Parent    child1    child2    child3
------------------------------------
111       112       113       117
111       222       223       224
444       441       442       443
```

I want to show in one row if each one of any ID is matching.

If user search 111 or 112 or 113 or 117 or 222 or 223 or 224, it has to show

```
111
112
113 
117
222
223
224
```

If user searches for 442, the result should be

```
444
441
442
443
```

Even if I use `case`, it will show in column, not by row

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can unpivot the results.  Here is one way:

```
select v.child
from relationdata rd outer apply
     (values (rd.child1), (rd.child2), (rd.child3), (rd.child4)) v(child)
where 111 in (rd.child1, rd.child2, rd.child3, rd.child4);
```

Note:  have four columns with references like that is usually a sign of a poor database design.  It would be better to have a relation table with a single `child` column and a "child number".

Comment: How to eliminate `NULL`

Comment: @mohamedfaiz . . . Add `and v.child is not null` to the `where` clause.

Comment: @mohamedfaiz Add "AND v.Child IS NOT NULL" to the WHERE clause.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thank you brother. I will accept your answer after 5 min